# AWS S3 multi-tenancy billing

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a multi tenancy (java web app) that store/transfer files using AWS S3.
Our customers are paying us for:
- Storage
- Data transfer

The calc of storage is very simple and it's ok for now, but my problem is calculate data transfer of our customers, this envolve partial download problems, etc.

I wan't know about your experience with this approach.

There's a way to explore this costs in a effective way?

For example: I send tenant-id and user-id on getObjectRequest. If there's a way to get this data is ok.

Anyone have a better idea to deal with that?

Comment: Does each customer have a dedicated S3 bucket? If so then maybe you can add a unique tag like Billto=customerx to each bucket and use cost allocation reports which should allow you to separate out costs by tags. See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/BucketBilling.html and http://www.slideshare.net/cloudability/cost-allocation-strategies-to-split-up-your-aws-bill.

Comment: Have you turned on logging for the S3 bucket?

Comment: Sorry guys, the customers share the same bucket.
Can I use tags for individual files?